# Trouble Using Java Command-Line Arguments in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have looked at every tutorial on using command-line arguments in NetBeans known to man and I am starting to think it's not me (famous last words)!

[image: Project Properties]

[image]

This image is from right-clicking on the project and going to the run tab. I set my main class appropriately, put in my arguments, but I'm still always hitting the line that says that the length of my arguments is less than 4. In fact, when I try to print args[0] I get a IndexOutOfBoundsException. Any thoughts?

Here is the top of my Java file, as requested!
[image: More complete file image]

**Also, here is another more simple example with it still not working as I would expect. I've tried to include all the steps I took:**

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

Womp.
[image: Step 4]

Comment: Can you include the code from above `public static void main(`, I have a feeling that the code you have shown us is not from your real main class `WordCloudGenerator`, but is from some other class.

Comment: You are using "Run file" from the right-click menu on a single class. That bypasses the project settings and just run that particular class. Use the Run command from the Project menu at the top instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce your issue in my environment, however the most likely cause is that:

Your main class is `WordCloudGenerator`, and from what I can tell the code in the image you have shown is not from `WordCloudGenerator` class.

You need to make sure that your main class is set correctly in the properties window shown in the first image in your question. Or if you do want two classes with main methods, then `WordCloudGenerator` needs to forward those `args` onto your other class like so:

```
public class WordCloudGenerator
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        myOtherClass.main(args);
    }
}
```

Now your main method in the other class should function correctly.

Comment: Note: If this is not your issue then please supply a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can see exactly what you are working with.